# скетч ардуины не принимает сигнал от питона

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

проблема следующего характера
Есть скрипт на питоне, который работает и в какой-то момент времени, должен послать арудине, команду на единоразовое выполнение скетча, простой клик мышкой ЛКМ и все

Связанные с ардуиной код питона

```
import serial                                 
ser = serial.Serial("COM3", 9600)
ser.write(1)
```

Скетч ардуины

```cpp
#include <Mouse.h>
 
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Mouse.begin();
}
 
void loop()
{
  if (Serial.available() > 0)
  {
     Mouse.click();
  }
}
```

Подскажите, где моя ошибка. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте что нибудь попороще для начала, например если пришел сигнал с Serial то включить LED_BUILTIN а вообще в вашем коде есть баг, вы не чиаете Serial то-есть вы проверяете есть ли данные в сериал порту, и потом ваш код зацикливается на том месте потому что вы данные так не разу и не считали. И получаеться что available всегда больше 0.

```
if (Serial.available() > 0) {
  incomingByte = Serial.read();
}
```

Да, чуть не забыл. Какой ардуиной пользуетесь? Для того то-бы работали классы Keyboard и Mouse у вас должна быть как минимум плата семейства `Due`

```
Hardware Required
Arduino Leonardo, Micro or Arduino Due board
```

Comment: да, у меня микро)  я проверял,все работает с чужим кодом,но с моим возникают сложности, спасибо , я воспользуюсь вашим решением, и более вдумчиво перечитаю гайды

Comment: Я раньше когда отладки по ком порту делал, зачастую пользовался вот ихней софтиной https://eterlogic.com/Products.VSPE.html можно замаппить виртульный порт, и сделать логрование состояний порта. Так-же сериал порт имеет очень много больных мест, стоит их учитвывать. Например что com не сразу запускаеться как надо. Зачастую первые байты бывают банальным мусором который надо просто выкидывать.